# Can a web application in a tomcat server be made aware when the other tomcat server in cluster go down?

Tags: java, tomcat8

I am working on clustering tomcat 8.5 server. It have 3 nodes. I could able to configure the cluster environment perfectly with 'BackupManager' for session replication.

I would like know, if web application (java code in war file) in tomcat nodes (say node 1 and node 2) can made be aware of, if say node 3 goes down.

Comment: How do they form a cluster?

Comment: I did not get your question.